# CSS/HTML : Background image Repeat-Y error

Tags: html, css

Hi please [take a look for better understanding](http://www.mystuff.comze.com/testimage.html).

Here background repeat-x is rendering smoothly while background repeat-Y renders with break.

```
<html> <head>
<style type="text/css">
.dark {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: white url('images/button_darkgrey_TPLinux_110x80.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;

 }
</style> </head>

< body>
  <div style="width: 500px; height: 350px; z-index: 1">
        <input type="button" class="dark" value="7"/>
  </div>
</body> </html>
```

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean by _break_. Do you want the background image stretched i.e. the top side of background image aligns with the top of button and bottom side of background aligns with bottom side of button?

Comment: exactly yes. I want vertically stretched image

Comment: Looks like it's not easily doable until CSS3 comes into its own...  There's info on how to fake it [here](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css3/f/blfaqbgsize.htm) (the example is for the entire page, but you should be able to extrapolate), but the code looks kinda ugly.  You'll probably have better luck just resizing your image or your button...

Comment: @Xavier: I tried to fix using that given example but unable to do that. One more thing the article tells how to fake and author's working example is just a fake to fools us.

Comment: @user575363 - [This example?](http://www.kyrnin.com/about/zfakebgstretchexample.htm)  It works - use Firebug to turn off the width and height CSS rules, and you'll see that it is, in fact, a small image that's been stretched by CSS (very much like that in Hussein's answer).  Note that in your case, you may have to add `position:relative` to your wrapper div to get the `position:absolute` on your img to work properly.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is set your background image and an image tag `<img class='dark' src="img.jpg" />` and give it the following css so it acts like a background.

```
.dark{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/P4rrP/1/

Comment: it's suggestion, Since the image URL is clearly part of the presentation (and not of the content), it should be placed in the CSS and not in the HTML.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Giving it `position:absolute` and `z-index:-1` will make it act as background.

Comment: thanks man. it's working with image <img  /> while i am using  **<input class="dark" >** (problem remains same)

Comment: I don't understand. You want background for input ??

Comment: yes for input type button. <input type="button" id="dark" />                  .      #dark { background: white url('images/button.jpg')
repeat left top; }